# Compare two different vector pairs

Tags: vectors

I have two different sets of vectors with the same dimension, $\dim = N$ where $N$ is around $300$. Assume a select a pair from set 1, $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then I select a pair from set 2, $u_1$ and $u_2$. I want to measure how similar hyperplanes that are composed of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $u_1$, $u_2$. In three dimensions, for instance, I would calculate the surface norms and compare these norms with each other. However, in high dimensions, I do not think this procedure will work. How can I do such a comparison?

Comment: Don't you need $N-1$ vectors to generate an hyperplan in $\dim N$ ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "surface norm".

Comment: @GerryMyerson it should be "surface normal", my bad.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec a . \vec b=0$ iff $a\perp b$, so consider $\vec v_1.\vec x=0$ and $\vec v_2.\vec x=0$ and find the core hyperplane (assuming a hyperplane is $1$ dimension below the space of dim $N$).